# Sorting the column names of a dataframe using alphabetic or number order

Tags: r

How is it possible to sort the columns of a dataframe using alphbetic or number order based on the last letter?

Example of column names:

```
variable_A variable_B variacle_C name_A name_B name_C
```

and the result be:

```
variable_A name_A variable_B name_B  variable_C name_C
```

Comment: In your example, this could be `x[order(substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)))]`.

Comment: Or `df[order(sub(".*_", "", names(df)))]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg this is the answer please put it as answer if you want. Do you know if I use numbers like `variable_1 variable_8 variacle_10 name_1 name_8 name_10` I take this: `variable_1 name_1 variable_10 name_10  variable_8 name_8` could be possible to take an order like we count `variable_1 name_1 variable_8 name_8  variable_10 name_10`

Comment: @Keri Before the `order` convert the `sub` to `numeric` i.e. `order(as.numeric(sub(...` as the output of `sub` is `character`.  Just to understand it try `sort(c("1", "8", "10", "4"))`

Comment: @akrun that's it. please if anyone of you both wants to put it as answer please make it because it answers my question.

Comment: @Keri It's DavidArenburg's answer.  I would urge him to do so.  In case, if he doesn't want, then you can post thatt as an answer.

Comment: I've posted an answer which will work for both character and numbers (represented as character) without the need to know about it apriori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove everything before (and including) the `_` using `sub` and then order your columns correctly (*regardless whenever the values represent strings or numbers*) using the `stringi::stri_order` while specifying `numeric = TRUE`

```
df[stringi::stri_order(sub(".*_", "", names(df)), numeric = TRUE)]
```